# Invalid Label - jQuery Ajax/Json request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, label

I've been pulling my hair out over this;

```
function status_update( token, loader ){
$("#status-submit").bind( 'click', function(){
    try{
        $("#status-feed-result").html( loader );
        $("#status-input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var status_input = $("#status-input").val();
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST', url: './', data: 'token=' + token + '&refresh=true&status-input=' + status_input + '&aj=true', cache: false, timeout: 5000, datatype: 'json',
            error: function(){ $("#status-input").removeAttr('disabled'); }, 
            success: function(html){ 
                auth(html); 
                $("#status-input").removeAttr('disabled'); 
                $("#status-input").val(''); 
                var JSON = eval(html);

                alert(JSON.PROFILE_STATUS); 

                //$(".status-p").html( JSON.PROFILE_STATUS );
                //$(".time").html( JSON.PROFILE_STATUS_TIME );
            }                           
        });
    }catch(err){}
    return false;                                           
});
}
```

I keep getting an error invalid label, what does this mean and how can I prevent from happening. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Exactly WHEN do you get the error?  On click?  On return of XHR?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it could be related to a jQuery repeat ajax call bug listed here: [jQuery Bug #8398](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8398)

It turns out that jQuery 1.5 is modifying subsequent ajax calls for json to jsonp which leads to this error.

I fixed it by following one of the workarounds suggested in the bug change history and placing the following code somewhere before my ajax calls are made:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   jsonp: null,
   jsonpCallback: null
});
```

Should fix any problems for other ajax requests too.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I wasn't specifying the success() function correctly. Try doing the following code where data is whatever information your passing back:

```
success : function(data,status,response){
```

EDIT:

My error was actually there because I was using a plug-in called validate.js. If you're using this plug-in and including validate.pack.js, this could be your problem.