# JQGrid 4.0 , jquery 1.5.2, MVC3 json response does not work anymore

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 application which worked just fine with jquery 1.4.2 and jqgrid 3.8. Now I wanted to upgrade to jquery 1.5.2 and jqgrid 4.0, but suddenly none of my grids are working. The error I get depends on which browser I use to do debugging. 
In chrome I get the following error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

and there error occurs in jquery on the instruction

```
head.insertBefore( script, head.firstChild );
```

(where script.innerText contains the json result returned from the server)

In firefox, with firebug I get the following

```
error:invalid label
```

and then it's showing the json

the json result I'm retrieving is quite simple and validates as correct json on jsonLint:

```
{
 "page" : 1,
 "total" : 0,
 "records" : 4,
 "rows" : [
      {
           "id" : "ip_524",
           "cell" : ["C", "Indeling1", 524]
      },
      {
           "id" : "ip_531",
           "cell" : ["E", "fe", 531]
      },
      {
           "id" : "ip_545",
           "cell" : ["MAX", "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890", 545]
      },
      {
           "id" : "ip_541",
           "cell" : ["ER", "Indeling1", 541]
      }]
}
```

ajaxsettings for jquery is set to traditional using
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

datatype for jqgrid is json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found an answer on stackoverflow ([Invalid Label - jQuery Ajax/Json request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606155/invalid-label-jquery-ajax-json-request))

Seems the following lines added to the javascript solves the problem:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   jsonp: null,
   jsonpCallback: null
});
```